# What is the definition of "Symbol" in the context of typescript compiler API?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I am looking for the definition and examples of the term "[Symbol](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d7c83f023eeb16027c5942b8156207e9f068b367/src/compiler/types.ts#L3774)" in the context of the typescript compiler API.

- how is it constructed?
- what is it used for?

Thank you!

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table help? See also the possible values of the `SymbolFlags` to get a feeling for what they might represent.

Comment: Hi, if you have to explain the concept in a few lines, how would you do it? I want to make sure my explanation makes sense.

Comment: No, I'd need an entire wikipedia article :-) If you have an explanation already, please post it in your question to make it less broad - then we have something specific to focus our answers on.